# Django social auth Data truncated for column 'uid' at row 1

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to integrate django social auth, but when facebook returns to my site, I'm getting this error:

```
Warning at /complete/facebook/
Data truncated for column 'uid' at row 1
```

I already used syncdb to create socialauth tables.

This is the entire traceback.

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://queromaiseducacao.com.br/complete/facebook/?redirect_state=Xb6dUCo869qmjI4Vj5y3Jle5fgRFr0PE&code=AQAm2DSP8YDG_mdq8GFq84B6kMOHUY1axVlOLlm39gqHBR1-cLqYx0mjDilVk0FInuoiGEIr5bMJASdhzD7rS_glKqV0BNI3BMlcsHc_4wqAFvOpdGWgCM6VZy8zvWEeyKDzrbOgiyeVpPbkQ70EOfee0VvnI6-qolFqg3vbvSknEJSUIOmtxnulZeXqQWn7YDTShVRnSwCqXebKoJhcWdswXuSoX52fUQmYmCdwM4uyIexoVXB4nQa-pRU4KUdhX--Tzk56Ay_2y3SMRmj2qK9kxYzLZ1E7ZUocjks_yZlAKUS7ecdTYFKUFdf9zHsVBds&state=Xb6dUCo869qmjI4Vj5y3Jle5fgRFr0PE



Traceback:
File "/home/filipefr2/webapps/quiz/lib/python2.7/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  112.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/filipefr2/webapps/quiz/lib/python2.7/django/views/decorators/csrf.py" in wrapped_view
  57.         return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/filipefr2/lib/python2.7/social_auth/decorators.py" in wrapper
  29.             return func(request, request.social_auth_backend, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/filipefr2/lib/python2.7/social_auth/views.py" in complete
  41.         return complete_process(request, backend, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/filipefr2/lib/python2.7/social_auth/views.py" in complete_process
  107.     user = auth_complete(request, backend, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/filipefr2/lib/python2.7/social_auth/views.py" in auth_complete
  190.     return backend.auth_complete(user=user, request=request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/filipefr2/lib/python2.7/social_auth/backends/facebook.py" in auth_complete
  164.             return self.do_auth(access_token, expires=expires, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/filipefr2/lib/python2.7/social_auth/backends/facebook.py" in do_auth
  206.         return authenticate(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/filipefr2/webapps/quiz/lib/python2.7/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py" in authenticate
  49.             user = backend.authenticate(**credentials)
File "/home/filipefr2/lib/python2.7/social_auth/backends/__init__.py" in authenticate
  114.         out = self.pipeline(pipeline, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/filipefr2/lib/python2.7/social_auth/backends/__init__.py" in pipeline
  143.                 result = func(*args, **out) or {}
File "/home/filipefr2/lib/python2.7/social_auth/backends/pipeline/social.py" in associate_user
  34.         social = UserSocialAuth.create_social_auth(user, uid, backend.name)
File "/home/filipefr2/lib/python2.7/social_auth/db/base.py" in create_social_auth
  194.         return cls.objects.create(user=user, uid=uid, provider=provider)
File "/home/filipefr2/webapps/quiz/lib/python2.7/django/db/models/manager.py" in create
  157.         return self.get_queryset().create(**kwargs)
File "/home/filipefr2/webapps/quiz/lib/python2.7/django/db/models/query.py" in create
  322.         obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
File "/home/filipefr2/webapps/quiz/lib/python2.7/django/db/models/base.py" in save
  545.                        force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
File "/home/filipefr2/webapps/quiz/lib/python2.7/django/db/models/base.py" in save_base
  573.             updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
File "/home/filipefr2/webapps/quiz/lib/python2.7/django/db/models/base.py" in _save_table
  654.             result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)
File "/home/filipefr2/webapps/quiz/lib/python2.7/django/db/models/base.py" in _do_insert
  687.                                using=using, raw=raw)
File "/home/filipefr2/webapps/quiz/lib/python2.7/django/db/models/manager.py" in _insert
  232.         return insert_query(self.model, objs, fields, **kwargs)
File "/home/filipefr2/webapps/quiz/lib/python2.7/django/db/models/query.py" in insert_query
  1514.     return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
File "/home/filipefr2/webapps/quiz/lib/python2.7/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in execute_sql
  903.             cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "/home/filipefr2/webapps/quiz/lib/python2.7/django/db/backends/util.py" in execute
  69.             return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
File "/home/filipefr2/webapps/quiz/lib/python2.7/django/db/backends/util.py" in execute
  53.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "/home/filipefr2/webapps/quiz/lib/python2.7/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py" in execute
  124.             return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py" in execute
  176.         if not self._defer_warnings: self._warning_check()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py" in _warning_check
  92.                     warn(w[-1], self.Warning, 3)

Exception Type: Warning at /complete/facebook/
Exception Value: Data truncated for column 'uid' at row 1
```

So, what's wrong with my tables?

Comment: Extend your `max_length` of the model field, it should solve the problem

Comment: Did you solve this problem????